# deploying mvc in iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm having 5 mvc application where i need to deploy it in IIS.

If I deploy it seprately each in IIS its working.

But I need in the following structure.

-> MyApplications under this all my mvc application need to be deployed.

I'm using IIS 7 and tried in IIS 6.x subversion also,

Show error like MyApplication/Mvcappl1 virtual path is using by another  application. But if host seprately it works

How can i do this.

Comment: This could help if you're trying IIS6: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please ensure you install MVC framework on the IIS 7 server.
Did you tried to convert the virtual directory as a web application under MyApplication? If not, open your IIS 7 managerment console->your website->MyApplication->Mvcappl1, right click,"Convert to application".